# AWS Amplify: How to make the ID the same value as the owner?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I want to create a User model and I want the User ID to always be equal to the Owner ID. 
How to do this?

This is my **schema.graphql** file content:

```
type User @model {
  id: ID! @default(value: @owner) # == owner
  name: String!
  description: String
  birthday: AWSDateTime
}
```

Thank you

Comment: The ID of your User model is the created ID for that DynamoDB table. You could just create a `userId: ID!` on your user model

Answer (score 1):

for my case, I just added sub from Congnito User:

```
type User
  @model
  @auth(rules: [{ allow: private, operations: [read] }, { allow: owner }]) 
  {
  id: ID!
  sub: String! @index(name: "bySub", queryField: "userBySub")
}
```

sub is retrieved from cognito thanks to Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser(), when you login for the first time a new user row is added to the dynamo table User.

Comment: You mentioned that when you login for the first time a new user row is added, but I'm not seeing that behavior.  What is the process that adds a new row to the `User` table?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the solution highlighted below:

```
type User
  @model
  @auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner, ownerField: "id" }
    { allow: private, operations: [read] }
  ])
{
  id: String @auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner, operations: [create, read, delete] } 
    { allow: private, operations: [read] }
  ])
  name: String!
  description: String
  birthday: AWSDateTime
}
```

I've specified on the model level `@auth` rules to use the `id` field as the "ownerField" and give other authenticated users a read access.

Then on the field level, I've removed the `update` access to the owner (again using `@auth` rules), so it is impossible to re-assign the record later on.